# Making nano accepting previous piped output as a file path

Tags: linux, pipe, nano

When I run the following command in linux:

```
find / -iname httpd.conf
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

I want to use nano to edit this file, lazy to type the file path again, I used:

```
find / -iname httpd.conf | nano
```

It didn't work, nano quickly opened and exited, then I found a nano.save file in the directory that I ran this command. Using cat command on nano.save, it outputs the text: /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf

This means nano thinks the previous piped output as a string that I want to write to a file, but the fact is, I would like nano to think it as the file path so that it actually opens the file for me to do the editing.

How can we make nano accept previous piped output as a file path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nano behaves like expected, since a pipe is used to connect on program's output to another one's input.

What you want instead is to use the output of `find` as an *argument* for `nano`:

```
nano `find / -iname httpd.conf`
```

Comment: But why does nano consider the input as the file content rather than the file path?

Comment: Because pipes connect output to inputs http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html. You want to substitute a `nano` parameter with a program output http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html.